# Compile with arbitrary array argument

Tags: compile, list-manipulation

I  need solve the task of classification of the points regarding their position. So I use such a function:

```
selector[mas_, reg_] := Select[mas, 
                      RegionMember[
                           Rectangle[{First@reg - st/2, Last@reg - st/2}, {First@reg + st/2, Last@reg + st/2}], 
                           #[[2]]] &];
```

It checks if second elements of `mas` entries are inside the rectangle defined by point `reg`. Finally it returns the list of right `mas` entries. There are ~4000 rectangles with ~250000 points and it evidently works too long.

I try to make the compiled version of such function:

```
  cs=Compile[{mas,_Real,4},{reg,_Real,2},
       Select[mas, 
             RegionMember[
                 Rectangle[{First@reg - st/2, Last@reg - st/2}, {First@reg + st/2, Last@reg + st/2}],
                 #[[2]]] &]
```

]

This function produce an error like "The first argument should be a 4 rank tensor". My array has a complicated form like `mas={{1,{123.4,654.3},{12.1,21.2}},{...},...}`. Of course it is not a good matrix but what is a problem with an arbitrary shape array?
I was trying make the packed array from the initial one but it does not help.

The question is how to compile a function with arbitrary shape array of Real arguments?

Comment: What are `reg` and `st`?

Comment: Do all the rectangles have the same size?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, `st` is an arbitrary number - the rectangle size. `reg` - is an arbitrary  point (pair of numbers) that defines the position of the rectangle. Yes, the sizes are equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not try to compile the brute-force algorithm. Instead you may use hierarchical data structures that allow the lookups in nearly linear time.

First read off all points `pts= mas[[All,2]]`. Then use `Nearest` to do the lookup (it employs a k-d-Tree). Simulating some data:

```
m = 4000;
n = 4000;
st = 0.5;
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, 2}];
rect = RandomReal[{-1 + st, 1 - st}, {n, 2}];
result = Nearest[pts -> "Index", rect, {\[Infinity], st/2}, DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];
```

Now `result[[k]]` contains all the indices of the points in the `k`-th rectangle (and hence the indixec for the rows of your original array).

Here a test for correctness:

```
k = 13;

Graphics[{
  Point[pts],
  EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[],
  Rectangle[rect[[k]] - st/2, rect[[k]] + st/2],
  Green, Point[pts[[result[[k]]]]]
  }]
```

[image]

For `m = 250000` this takes two seconds on my machine.

Comment: It is very interesting approach. Thanks, will try!

Comment: You're welcome! Btw., if you want to apply this to general axis-aligned rectangles then you merely have to scale the coodinates (by multiplying `pts` and `rect` with an appropriate diagonal matrix from the right) before calling `Nearest`.